# Alternative workflow to using jupyter notebook (aka how to avoid repetitive initialization delay)?

Tags: python, initialization, delay, jupyter-notebook

Usually the main reason I'm using jupyter notebook with python is the possibility to initialize once (and only once) objects (or generally "data") that tend to have long (lets say more than 30 seconds) loading times. When my work is iterative, i.e. I run minimally changed version of some algorithm multiple times, the accumulated cost of repeated initialization can get large at end of a day.

I'm seeking an alternative approach (allowing to avoid the cost of repeated initialization without using a notebook) for the following reasons:

- No "out of the box" version control when using notebook.
- Occasional problems of "I forgot to rename variable in a single place". Everything keeps working OK until the notebook is restarted.
- Usually I want to have usable python module at the end anyway.
- Somehow when using a notebook I tend to get code that if far from "clean" (I guess this is more self discipline problem...).

Ideal workflow should allow to perform whole development inside IDE (e.g. pyCharm; BTW linux is the only option). Any ideas?

I'm thinking of implementing a simple (local) execution server that keeps the problematic objects pre-initialized as global variables and runs the code on demand (that uses those globals instead of performing initialization) by spawning a new process each time (this way those objects are protected from modification, at the same time thanks to those variables being global there is no pickle/unpickle penalty when spawning new process).

But before I start implementing this - maybe there is some working solution or workflow already known?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code + Python extension works fine (both Windows and Mac, not sure about Linux). Very fast and lightweight, Git integration, debugging refactorings, etc.

Also there is an IDE called Spyder that is more Python-specific. Also works fine but is more heavy-weight.

Comment: It looks visual studio code has a possibility to [run selection inside jupyter kernel](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Jupyter-(IPython)). Linux seems to be also supported, Ill give it a try